# Kohana ORM relations - how

Tags: orm, key, kohana, has-many, has-one

I am trying to build a simple relation between two tables.
Unfortunately, the ORM searches for another column from the parent model:

```
<?php
class Model_Hreflang extends ORM {
[...]
protected $_table_columns = array(
        'id'            => NULL,
        'domain_id'         => NULL,
        'country_code_id'   => NULL,
        'language_code_id'  => NULL
    );

    protected $_has_many = array(
        'cc' =>
            array(
                'model'=> 'Country2', 
                **'WHAT TO PUT HERE'** => 'country_code_id',
                'foreign_key' => 'country_code'),
}
```

When trying to get a related record to the first table, the query is made like 
**"hreflang".id = "country2".country_code**
and I need to change it, for example to
**"hreflang".country_code_id = "country2".country_code**

Anyone managed to do it by the ORM?
Thanks!
Anton

Comment: Can you describe the relationship you want in words?

Comment: Hi kingkero. I wish to connect a favourite column from ORM model A to a favourite column to ORM model B.
I cannot manage to join column A.c1 to a column B.c2. My Kohana ORM always tries to join like A.id to B.c2.

Comment: You should be able to do this via `far_key` & `foreign_key` (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3592858/1557526) or other examples from SO)

Answer (score 0):

I think you schould set it by belongs to

```
protected $_belongs_to = array('cc' => array('model' => 'Country2', 'foreign_key' => 'country_code'));
```

read more here: http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/orm/relationships